# How do I enable the preprocessor in gcc assembly

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I am using the GCC like this:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -fno-leading-underscore -m32 -c -o obj/entry.o src/entry.s
```

However, when I compile the linker says:

```
ld -melf_i386 -T kernel.ld -o kernel obj/entry.o obj/init.o
obj/entry.o:(multiboot+0x0): undefined reference to `MB_MAGIC'
obj/entry.o:(multiboot+0x4): undefined reference to `MB_FLAGS'
obj/entry.o:(multiboot+0x8): undefined reference to `MB_CHECKSUM'
```

Those references are defined in the entry.s file with the preprocessor:

```
#define MB_MAGIC 0x1badb002
#define MB_FLAGS 0x0
#define MB_CHECKSUM -(MB_MAGIC + MB_FLAGS)
```

How can I enable preprocessing?

Comment: Name the file `smurf.S` instead of `smurf.s`.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html says it does...

Comment: Nevermind, `make` didn't realise that a name change is a change. Works now. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in [gcc's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html), if the file name ends in capital `.S`, it will be preprocessed automatically. You can add the `-v` option to see what steps gcc follows. If you don't want to change the file name, you can also specify the language with `-x assembler-with-cpp` (before the file name).